# How to automatically logon without losing the classic shutdown menu?

Tags: windows-xp, passwords, shutdown, automatic-logon

I recently followed these [steps](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-disable-new-xp-style-welcome-screen-log-off-and-shutdown-dialog-box-in-windows-xp/) to get the classic shutdown menu in windows XP:
[image]

Now my system, which normally doesn't require a password, prompts me for a password when I try to login.  Is there a way to have both this classic shutdown menu AND have it auto log  me in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a registry edit described [here on the MS kb.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231)

The reason it changed for you is, I am guessing you only have one user and when you reverted to the classic screens it is prompting for a login now.  The registry edit will allow you to login your preferred user automatically.

Comment: So it worked?  ?

Comment: This answer wanted me to add values to the registry... I ended up going with TomWij's answer as that just used a built in windows tool that did it for me, but was too late to change the accepted answer.

Comment: @Dan - Thanks for the update, I upvoted Tom's answer in compensation :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can [configure Windows XP to automatically login](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/Autologon.htm).

It shouldn't break the classic shutdown menu as far as I am aware of it...